# Surface tension in a water drop

Tags: forces, water, fluid-statics, surface-tension

[image]

Consider the above image

This is a pretty standard diagram but it makes no sense to me. I have some questions regarding it.

---

1. Why are we taking surface tension of air-solid interface into consideration for finding the shape of the drop? It appears to me that it is not acting on the drop but on solid.
2. Which surface are the different forces acting on?
3. What exactly balances the Resultant Force due to the three forces?

Comment: My impression is this diagram is most relevant to depict the quantities in Young's Relation (Young-Dupre Equation), but it is not the most useful diagram to understand the important quantities relevant to a water droplet (surface tension, forces, pressure, etc).